Length 2 complete reducibility implies length $n$ complete reducibility?
Suppose for some (associative unital) ring $R$ we have that all length 2 modules are completely reducible.
Is it then the case that all finite length modules are completely reducible?
I'm particularly interested in the case when $R$ is a finitely generated algebra over a field.

We induct on the length $n$ of the module. Let $R$ be a ring such that all length-2 $R$-modules are semisimple, let $M$ be a module of length $n+1$, $n≥2$, and let $S \leq M$ be simple. Then $length(M/S)=n$, so by induction we have $$M/S= \bigoplus_{i=1}^n N_i/S$$ with $N_i/S$ simple. Clearly each $N_i$ has length 2, so by assumption, there exist simple $P_i \leq M$ such that $N_i=S \oplus P_i$. Now for any $m \in M$, we can decompose in $M/S$: $$m+S=\sum_{i=1}^n s_i+p_i+S$$ for some $s_i \in S$ and $p_i \in P_i$. So $m$ can be written as a sum of elements in $S$ and $P_i$. We have written $$M=S + \sum_{i=1}^n P_i$$ as a sum of simple submodules, which is equivalent to being completely reducible/semisimple.

For finite dimensional algebras over a field, the answer is yes. Take any simple module $X$ and look at its injective hull $I(X)$. The assumption that length 2 modules are completely reducible implies that the length of $I(X)$ cannot be $\ge 2$; otherwise, the socle of $I(X)$ would not be $X$. Thus $I(X) = X$. This shows every simple module is injective. It now follows by induction on length that every module is completely reducible.
